# UserVisibilityHint function is not called every time when fragmnent is viable

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 4 fragments in my viewpager I want to send a call for data every time when my fragment is visible to user. I am using uservisibilityhint() function but it is called only first time in view page and then again it is never called whenever that fragment is visible . is there any way to call it manually every time when the fragment is visible so that I can now that my fragment is  visible or not to the user . how can i do this thing

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: i already wrote in my question that this function is called only for first time then it is never called

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Listener` on your `ViewPager` in the `Activity` like below:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener...
```

and here in the listeners callback detect the current View using this method:

```
ViewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

and then wire an interface between your activity and four fragments so you can notify which View should try loading fresh data.